# Replace in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to replace all birth that I have from EX : 199500 to 1995 so how can I remove all 2 zeros in my column?

I used this:

```
select P_BIRTH from city.dbo.personsuly replace(P_BIRTH,00, ,);
```

Comment: What data type is that column?

Comment: Remove 00 doesn't work, consider 199002.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE city.dbo.personsuly

SET P_BIRTH = LEFT(P_BIRTH, 4)
```

When you use LEFT function, you can select a set of charachters from the original column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `left()` function instead of using `replace()`

```
select left(P_BIRTH, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
select stuff(P_BIRTH, charindex('00', P_BIRTH), 2, '') from city.dbo.personsuly
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this -

```
UPDATE city.dbo.personsuly
SET P_BIRTH = P_BIRTH / 100
```

**Example** ..This can also work with string data types.

```
SELECT 199500  / 100

-----------
1995

(1 row affected)
```